# How to hide press any key to continue when running powershell script in c++

Tags: c++, powershell

Below is the C++ code where I am running powershell script. The script is running fine but after the script is completed it is asking to press any key in command prompt.

c++

```
    void main()
    {
        string strPath = "D:\Share\Mail.ps1";      
        system("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F D:\\Share\\Mail.ps1"); 
        executeFile();              

    }
```

Powershell:

```
    $SmtpServer = 'smtp.server.net'  
    $SmtpPort = '2525'
    $SmtpUser = 'test'  
    $smtpPassword = '**********'  
    $MailtTo = 'test@gmail.com'
    $MailFrom = 'test@test.com'  
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $SmtpUser,                                 
                   $($smtpPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
    $MailSubject = 'Alert : Breach Notification'
    $Body = 'Test'
    $MailCount=0
    $file = 'Test_10242019_5.20.txt'

    Send-MailMessage -To $MailtTo -from $MailFrom -Subject $MailSubject -Body $Body -Attachment 
             $file -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $SmtpPort  -UseSsl -Credential $Credentials
```

[Command prompt giving Press any key to continue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vClev.png)

How can I hide this cmd.

Comment: How are you running your C++ code? via Visual Studio ?

Comment: Try to place an exit-statement after sendmail.

Comment: Yes, I am running it in Visual Studio

Comment: I tried exit after sendemail but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#include <Windows.h>` at the begining of your `main.cpp`

and at the end of your `Main` function, add:

`HWND wnd = GetConsoleWindow(); 
ShowWindow(wnd, 0);`

Comment: Your welcome !
Can you mark your question as done :) ?